# Foundations of Differential Calculus

Tags: calculus, foundations, differential

In the preface of Foundations of Differential Calculus there's a section that says:

> Thus, if the quantity $x$ is given an increment $\omega$, so that
>   it becomes $x + \omega$, its square $x^2$ becomes $x^2 + 2x\omega + \omega^2$, and it takes the
>   increment $2x\omega + \omega^2$. Hence, the increment of $x$ itself, which is $\omega$, has the
>   ratio to the increment of the square, which is $2x\omega+\omega^2$, as $1$ to $2x+\omega$. This
>   ratio reduces to $1$ to $2x$, at least when $\omega$ vanishes.

$f(x) = x^2$

$f(x+w) = (x+\omega)^2 = x^2 + 2x\omega + \omega^2$

$(x+\omega)^2 - x^2 = 2x\omega+\omega^2$

And then the part I don't understand where $\omega = 2x\omega+\omega^2$ goes to "as $1$ to $2x+\omega$".

Comment: maybe it is better to do $\frac{(x+\omega)^2-x^2}{\omega}=2x+\omega$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph says that the increment of $x$ (which means $(x + \omega) - x$, i.e. $\omega$) and the corresponding increment of $f$ from $f(x) = x^2$ to $f(x + \omega) = x^2 + 2 \omega x + \omega ^2$ (which means $f(x + \omega) - f(x) = 2 \omega x + \omega ^2$) have the ratio

$$\frac {(x + \omega) - x} {f(x + \omega) - f(x)} = \frac {\omega} {2 \omega x + \omega ^2} = \frac 1 {2 x + \omega}$$

which, when $\omega \to 0$, is exactly $\frac 1 {2x}$.

This prepares you mentally for later considering the limit of the reversed fraction:

$$\lim \limits _{\omega \to 0} \frac {f(x + \omega) - f(x)} {(x + \omega) - x} = 2x ,$$

which is an illustration of the concept of "derivative".

Comment: I get it now, thanks. The language was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

In all retrospect a matrix is required for the reduction of the equation in order to satisfy f(x) and (w) where the equation should read after reduction:

(x+w) (x+w) = x^2 + xw + wx + w^2 there exists a matrix conversion if one can find the matter of the originating question and can deduct or otherwise predict and therewith have more control over the formulizations within the equation before the question is solved itself .That would be a square matrix with wx first and then xw underneath for the matrix will give the answer to 2xw + w2 or if xw is first the answer to 2wx + w^2 which version of the matrix would be incorporated over in cellular reproduction by degradation regradation where omega plays a large role on this in cooling and eliminating alpha decay mode due to frequency.
It would be my belief that the wx first would be correct unless enduring some form of replication from chromosomes or any form of cellular type action involved in the equation as the existing formulization of w should already be present and upon summoning it should be provided in ancilliary support to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The text shaded in khaki has numerator and denominator interchanged in its last part. Instead it should read as follows:

Thus, if the quantity $x$ is given an increment $ω$, so that
it becomes $x + ω$. In this way the square $x^2$ becomes $x^2 + 2xω + ω^2$, so that the square takes the increment $2xω + ω^2$. Hence, the ratio of the increment of the square, which is $2xω+ω^2$, to the increment of $x$ itself, which is $ω$, is $2x+ω$. This ratio reduces  to $2x$ when $ω$ is "negligible", or "goes to $0$".